# Words like astronaut for dimensional traveller

Tags: single-word-requests

I was looking for a word like astronaut but for dimensional traveling, so I looked up latin for Dimension and got ratio, so Rationaut (dimension sailor) I guess. However I did not like how that sounded so I tried latin for reality (rem) and made Remnaut (Reality sailor). I just want to know if either of these words make sense for what I am trying to say, or if there is an already established word for what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both your words make sense for what you want to say in terms of meaning. But I agree with you that they don’t ‘sound’ quite right. I wonder if that could be because you’ve used Latin for the first halves while the second half is Greek. So I used Google Translate to find the Greek equivalents:

dimension: [διάσταση (*diástasi*)](https://translate.google.com/#en/el/dimension)

reality: [πραγματικότητα (*pragmatikótita*)](https://translate.google.com/#en/el/reality)

So you could get:

*pragmatikonaut*: too long

*pragmonaut*: implies a connection with ‘pragmatic’ in English, which has a completely different meaning

*diastonaut*: not sure if the sound of it is what you’re looking for

I Google Translate-ed a couple of related words and found:

interstellar: [διάστερος (*diásteros*)](https://translate.google.com/#en/el/interstellar)

between/inter: [μεταξύ (*metaxý*)](https://translate.google.com/#en/el/between)

Which gives you a few other options:

*diastronaut*: connects with ‘astronaut’ and implies something more than that, but may sound too clunky

*metaxonaut*: sounds vaguely space-y, but not sure if that's what you're going for

*metanaut*: relates to 'beyond' in English, so would be easy for most English speakers to understand, but again, not sure if that's what you're going for

I hope all this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You have tried the Latin, but there is already a Greek word which expresses what you are describing.

> γε, ge, is the Greek for the Earth.
>
> λαος, laos, is the word for the peoples of the earth, the nations.
>
> αγ, ag, is a prefix which negates that which follows it.

So αγ-γε-λαος, aggelos, is the Greek word for 'that which is not of the earth or the peoples'.

And we have already brought that word into English as **angel.**

Comment: Thus their city, Los Angeles.

Comment: That is not the Greek etymology of άγγελος.